# Launchpadlib how to get bug id from bug_link

Tags: python, launchpadlib

I'm not sure if this is a python question or a launchpad question since I am new to both.  I am getting a collection of bugs in a bug_task collection.  I am running searchTasks.  The API reference documentation says bug_link is a link to a bug object.  The bug object has the id.  I was hoping to be able to print out the bug id by just getting the attribute, but that is not working.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
bug_tasks = series.searchTasks(status=['New'],importance=['Critical'])
for bug in bug_tasks:
    print(bug)
    bug_link=bug.bug_link
    bug_id=bug_link.id
    print(bug_id)
```

When I run the script, I get the error

```
https://api.launchpad.net/devel/ubuntu/xenial/+source/linux/+bug/1626158
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_ubuntu_bug_list.py", line 39, in <module>
    bug_id=bug_link.id
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I've also tried

```
bug_id=bug_link.get(id)
bug_id=get(bug_link.id)
bug_id=get(bug_link).id
```

None of those worked.

Any help on how to get the bug id from bug_link would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What's the link to the docs that you mention? Problem is that `bug.bug_link` is a string and you're thinking it also has the `id` as attribute. My guess would be `bug.id` instead.

Comment: I was looking at the launchpad API pages, https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib, and https://launchpad.net/+apidoc/devel.html.  I was hoping for an easy way to get the id from the bug object.  Instead, I went with getting the last part of the bug string (bug_id = bug_task.bug_link.split('/')[-1]) and using that to get the bug object (bug = launchpad.bugs[bug_id]).  Not ideal to me, but it works.  I was hoping to be able to use the launchpad module to be able to do some query to get the bug object.